# У нас нет в деревне дома(,) большего, чем мой

Tags: запятые

Я прочитал Розенталя и думаю, что здесь запятая не нужна. Так?

`У нас нет в деревне дома(,) большего, чем мой.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно:

*У нас нет в деревне дома **бОльшего, // чем мОй.***

Определительный оборот **не обособляется**, так как является **смысловым центром** высказывания (на него падает ударение).  В данном случае нет не просто дома, а дома бОльшего. Интонационно предложение делится **на две** фонетические фразы.

**[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108#pp108)**

**Пункт 6.** При отсутствии предшествующего определения последующие одиночные определения **обособляются или не обособляются** в зависимости от степени их **интонационно-смысловой** близости с определяемым существительным. Ср.:

*А запорожцы, и пешие и конные, выступали на три дороги к трём воротам (Г.); …Особенно понравились мне глаза, большие и грустные (Т.);*  В этих примерах существительное не нуждается в **обязательном** определении (связь между ними **слабая**).

*Вместо весёлой петербургской жизни, ожидала меня скука **в стороне глухой и отдалённой** (П.); Под этой толстой серой шинелью билось **сердце страстное и благородное** (Л.)*; В этих примерах существительное нуждается **в определении**, без него высказывание не имеет **законченного смысла**.

Comment: Ладно, в этом случае соглалусь, плюс к ответу.

Answer (score 0):

***У нас нет в деревне дома, большего, чем мой.***

Запятая ставится перед **определительным оборотом**. Придаточное *чем мой* — это как бы «зависимое слово» — *большего (чем чей?), чем мой*, — но оно не входит в оборот, но запятая всë же ставится.

Comment: Максим, вы уверены в своем ответе?

Comment: @Sharon Уверен.

Comment: Запятая перед оборотом вызывает сомнения.

Comment: @Sharon И почему же это?

Comment: Смысловой центр высказывания. Уберите оборот, и что получится?  Да еще маленькое предложение на три части разделили.

Comment: Максим, ещё раз (только не обижайтесь). Ваши ответы бездоказательны, вы просто торопитесь. Ответы типа "Я сказал – значит, так правильно" не имеют ценности. В вашем профиле написано: "Я здесь в первую очередь для того, чтобы его [русский язык] изуч**и**ть". Так не получится. Язык текуч, поэтому его всё время приходится изуч**а**ть.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Профиль тут причем? А бездоказательны всегда не только мои ответы. Все по правилам пишу. Могу, конечно, и ошибаться, но ссылки необязательны, если ты знаешь правила. Прочитаю про определительные обороты, пожалуй.

Comment: **При том**, что нужно быть внимательным во всём, так как мы находимся на сайте русского языка. Например, прежде чем отправить ответ или вопрос (и система об этом предупреждает), проверьте его. Хотя бы на предмет опечаток, ненужных повторов и прочих неточностей.

Comment: @Sharon Можете ссылку, опять же, дать. В «Розентале» про смысловой центр не нашел. Где про это написано, чтоб мне убедиться, что верно и без запятой?

Comment: Максим, мы не всегда даем ссылки, но у отвечающего должна быть ссылка на правило, которым он пользуется. У вас могут  попросить  дать ссылку в любой момент для доказательства.   http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108#pp108 Пункт 6.  Вместо весёлой петербургской жизни, ожидала меня скука в стороне глухой и отдалённой (П.); Под этой толстой серой шинелью билось сердце страстное и благородное (Л.);  в этих примерах существительное нуждается в определении, без него высказывание не имеет законченного смысла.

Comment: Жду контрответ Шерон.

Comment: На этот вопрос?

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Тоже интересно.

Comment: Ну конечно же-с!